# Edited array row in phpmyadmin and broke it

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization, phpmyadmin

I have a row which has an array stored like like this:

```
a:10:{s:4:"full";s:79:"https://example.com...
```

I edited it slightly (just the URL) and now I can't retrieve it as an array anymore. Why? What can I do to turn it back?

I'm guessing it has to do with it being serialized or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WordPress stores the array data in a serialized way, so it `s:79`
>   represent the length of `https://example.com...`.

How to maker it working:  replace `79` with your current URL length.

For example:

```
s:18:"https://google.com"
```

Hope this helps!